# Will RestSharp support Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, universal

I was trying to update an existing WP8 Silverlight application to an Universal application, but RestSharp won't install using NuGet because it does not support Universal Apps.

Will this be supported in the near future or is there an alternative I could use?

Comment: You could post an issue on Github. In the mean time, you could compile from source. One, like the WP8 version may work without modification (or very little modification).

Comment: You've tried PortableRest? https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest I've been using it in PCL's and I thought it's Universal Apps ready

Comment: @WiredPrairie, Thanks, yes, [I did](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/530), however there is not much activity there. It seemed that someone also tried to compile from source, [but did have some issues with that](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/526).

Comment: @Depechie, thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @Depechie, no joy, PortableRest does not support Authentication at this time. [The author is working on it though](https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest/issues/27)..

Comment: Ok was unaware about that

Comment: Just take a look at this: http://chris.millr.org/get-restsharp-working-on-windows-phone-8-1-and-universal-apps/

Answer (score 3):

There is a RestSharp fork called "RestSharpPortable", that is compatible to portable libraries (and therefor also in universal apps).

Find it here:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable/1.9.1

Chris Millar provided a workaround here:
http://chris.millr.org/get-restsharp-working-on-windows-phone-8-1-and-universal-apps/

You should ask the restsharp team for Universal App support on their project page.
But as far as I can tell you: Multiple people have asked for it in the last year and nobody ever replied... So the answer is properly NO for the forseeable future.